# Ionic AngularJS parent animation not running correctly when triggered in child controller

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework, animation

I have been trying this for days now.

I have a parent controller `MainCtrl` that is wired to a background layer `bgId`. (This is outside the `ion-nav-view`)
A child of this controller is `HomeCtrl`. (Inside the 'ion-nav-view')
HomeCtrl has a button that when pressed it should:
a) transition to the next State
b) change the color of `bgId` layer.
I can get the `bgId` layer to change, but the transition does not run smoothly - it just pops into place.
If I disable either of the animations then the other works fine, but with both enabled I get the annoying popping effect.

Does anyone have any ideas about what the solution is?

Edit: Here are some relevant code sections.  //.... = code removed for clarity

**index.html**

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">        
    <div id="bgId" class="{{colorVal}}">
        <ion-nav-bar>
            <ion-nav-back-button mylohit="changeColour()" class="button-clear" data-mylocurrpage="0" data-mylonxtpage="0" >
            </ion-nav-back-button>                
        </ion-nav-bar>            
        <ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right">
        </ion-nav-view>
    </div> 
</body>
```

**app.css**

```
.greenBg-add, .greenBg-remove,
.redBg-add, .redBg-remove,
.blueBg-add, .blueBg-remove,
.yellBg-add, .yellBg-remove,
.purpBg-add, .purpBg-remove {
  -webkit-transition: background 1000ms linear !important;
  -moz-transition: background 1000ms linear !important;
  -o-transition: background 1000ms linear !important;
  transition: background 1000ms linear !important; }

.greenBg,
.greenBg-add.greenBg-add-active {
  background-color: #9BDB25; }

.redBg,
.redBg-add.redBg-add-active {
  background-color: #D62459; }

.blueBg,
.blueBg-add.blueBg-add-active {
  background-color: #51DBD8; }

.yellBg,
.yellBg-add.yellBg-add-active {
  background-color: #D8DB51; }

.purpBg,
.purpBg-add.purpBg-add-active {
  background-color: #662eb4; }
```

**app.js**

```
var myloApp = angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.servicesConnect', 'app.servicesData', 'app.servicesAuth', 'app.services', 'app.directives', 'ionic.utils', 'firebase', 'ngCordova', 'ngAnimate']);
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl'    
  })  
  .state('page1', {
    url: '/page1',
    templateUrl: 'templates/page1.html',
    controller: 'Page1Ctrl'    
  })
  .state('page2', {
    url: '/page2',
    templateUrl: 'templates/page2.html',
    controller: 'Page2Ctrl'    
  });

  //....

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');  
}]);
```

**controllers.js**

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'ServicesMisc', 'ServicesAuth', function ($scope, $state, ServicesMisc, ServicesAuth) {        
    //....    
    $scope.colorVal = 'redBg';  //initial class colour
    $scope.prevColorVal = 'redBg';

    $scope.changeColour = function () {
        console.log('main : change colour');
    };    
    //....
}])
.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', 'ServicesAuth', 'ServicesData', 'ServicesMisc', function ($scope, ServicesAuth, ServicesData, ServicesMisc) {        
    //....        
    $scope.changeColour = function () {
        console.log('home : change colour');
    };        
    //....
}])
.controller('Page1Ctrl', ['$scope', 'ServicesAuth', 'ServicesData', 'ServicesMisc', function ($scope, ServicesAuth, ServicesData, ServicesMisc) {
    //....        
    $scope.changeColour = function () {
        console.log('page1 : change colour');
    };        
    //....
}]);
```

**templates/home.html**

```
<ion-view title="Home">
    <ion-content ng-controller="HomeCtrl" id="homeCont">
        <div class="container">
        //....
            <div class="home-btns-cont">
                <a mylohit="changeColour()" data-mylocurrpage="0" data-mylonxtpage="1" class="txtWhite home-btns-text button icon-right ion-plus-round button-clear button-dark">new entry</a>
            </div>
            <div class="home-btns-cont">
                <a mylohit="changeColour()" data-mylocurrpage="0" data-mylonxtpage="4" class="txtWhite home-btns-text button icon-right ion-stats-bars button-clear button-dark">view stats</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**directives.js**

```
angular.module('app.directives', [])
.directive('mylohit', function ($rootScope, $state) {    
    var pageArr = [{home:'redBg'}, {page1:'greenBg'}, {page2:'yellBg'}, {page3:'blueBg'}, {page4:'purpBg'}, {page5:'blueBg'}];
    var pagelen = pageArr.length;    
    var colInit = pageArr[0];   
    var backPageCol = colInit.page2;    

    return function (scope, element, attrs) {  

        var nextPageNum = attrs.mylonxtpage;
        var currPageNum = attrs.mylocurrpage;
        var obj = pageArr[nextPageNum];
        var item = Object.keys(obj);
        var objItem = obj[item];

        element.bind('click', function () { 
            $rootScope.$$childHead.prevColorVal = currPageNum;            
            $rootScope.$$childHead.colorVal = objItem; 

                $state.transitionTo(item[0]);           
        });        
    };
})
```

Comment: Can you replicate it in a Plunker? Or at least show the relevant HTML, CSS and JS. Will be much easier for people to help.

Comment: @tasseKATT - thanks, I have added updated my original post to contain some code. (not managed to get ionic working yet in Plunker)

Comment: I'm away for a few days without computer access, but I will take a look at it when I get home.

Comment: Sorry, too much code to look through without a working example. If you can reproduce it in a Plunker it would be much easier. Here is a start: http://plnkr.co/edit/X8oc7roKyOMRwlAGvLri?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

@tasseKATT had the right idea!

I finally managed to get the code into a plunker and fix the issue.
Basically, I replaced my curr ionic.bundle.js with the plunker version and it all started working.

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl"> 
    <div id="bgId" class="{{colorVal}}">
        <ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right">
        </ion-nav-view>
    </div>
    <button swapcolour="changeColour()" data-nxtpage="1">change colour</button>
</body>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Oug8zD?p=preview

I updated the answer here:
[Angular animate parent div of ng-view using element insde ng-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29365713/angular-animate-parent-div-of-ng-view-using-element-insde-ng-view)