# Angular animate parent div of ng-view using element insde ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, css-animations

Is it possible to css animate a div (background-color) that is outside the ng-view, using a directive on a $state inside the ng-view?

The ng-view has css animations for the routing.

If I do not animate the div then the ng-view anims work fine, but..
If I add animation classes to the div(bgId) then the routing anims do not fire.

Here is a sample of html: (Button added as example - would normally be in the template pages eg. home.html / login.html )

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl"> 
    <div id="bgId" class="{{colorVal}}">
        <ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right">
        </ion-nav-view>
    </div>
    <button swapcolour="changeColour()" data-nxtpage="1">change colour</button>
</body>
```

This is controlled by a directive(swapcolour) that gets the nxtpage value from the button attr and updates the colorVal in MainCtrl.

//MainCtrl.js

```
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state) {
    $scope.colorVal = 'redBg';
}])
```

//Directive.js

```
.directive('swapcolour', function ($rootScope, $state) {
    var pageArr = [{home:'redBg'},{login:'blueBg'}];

    return function (scope, element, attrs) {        

        var nextPageNum = attrs.nxtpage;           
        var obj = pageArr[nextPageNum];
        var item = Object.keys(obj);
        var objItem = obj[item];

        element.bind('click', function () {
            $state.transitionTo(item[0]);      
            $rootScope.$$childHead.colorVal = objItem;
        });
    }
}])
```

I do not know why it fails. Any ideas?? I am new to directives. (Trying to setup a plunker, but having issues getting ionic working with it)

Comment: Are you running the animations at the same time? Can you give more information? Are you using ngAnimate?

Comment: Hi, @jguimaraes I am using Ionic, ui.router, ngAnimate etc. I am trying to run the css3 animations at the same time (is this possible??), I have tried it with both ui-sref and ng-click (gives same result). I am currently using a custom directive on a button that activates the page routing, and updates the {{colorVal}} variable (this activates the ccs animation).

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it! - I think.
Basically after totally stripping the application to its bones I managed to build a plunker and got it working.

There was nothing wrong with my code after all.

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl"> 
    <div id="bgId" class="{{colorVal}}">
        <ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right">
        </ion-nav-view>
    </div>
</body>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Oug8zD?p=preview

Then I tried this code on my app - and it still did not work! So I tried replacing my ionic.bundle.js and ionic.css files (orig installed using npm) with the files used in the plunker (1.0.0-rc.1) and my app worked :)

Hope this helps others in trouble in the future.